# How to fix iCal wrong date after snow leopard upgrade?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, calendar.app, date

I searched google everywhere but could not find a fix for that annoying bug.

This video shows exactly what happens: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsie6lN0p8o

Removing from the doc and re-adding does not fix the problem. It comes back later... :-(

Anyone with a final fix for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your video is offline, this question therefore doesn't make sense in its current form anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the combo update for your Mac OS X version. It's available on support.apple.com. Just google for e.g. "10.6.7 combo update", if you want to update/restore OS X 10.6.7, or any other version number.

Comment: @Gareth See the edit history on the reason why I suggest using a search engine instead of providing a link. Reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling iCal from the Snow Leopard disc is probably the best bet.

Comment: Is it possible to reinstall only iCal form the disk?